# Execute system command after compile

Tags: shell-escape

I'm using `\immediate\write18{...}` to create a temporary file that is used in the document body, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\immediate\write18{sed 's/foo/bar/' in.tsv > out.tmp}

\begin{document}
% Do stuff with out.tmp
\end{document}
```

I would like to delete the temp file `out.tmp` once the compilation is done, something like:

```
\onExit\write18{rm out.tmp}
```

or

```
...
\end{document}
\write18{rm out.tmp}
```

Is this possible?

If it matters, I'm compiling with `pdflatex --shell-escape slides.tex`

Comment: `\write` happens as the page is shipped out (even write18)  so you need to have it on, not after,  the last page. (or perhaps simpler just arrange that your pipeline deletes the file after running latex)

Comment: There is `\AtEndDocument`, which does what your `\onExit` suggestion would do I think, i.e., in the middle of a document you can specify a command to be run at the end. Technically the command is executed as if it was placed before `\end{document}`, but I guess that shouldn't make a difference for your use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `atveryend` package:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.tsv}
foo
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{atveryend}

\immediate\write18{sed 's/foo/bar/' \jobname.tsv > \jobname.tmp}
\AtVeryEndDocument{\immediate\write18{rm \jobname.tmp}}

\begin{document}

\input{\jobname.tmp}

\end{document}
```

This will print “bar” and there will be no `.tmp` file at the end. I changed the file names in order not to risk clobbering my files, but you can use whatever name you please.

Where does `\AtVeryEndDocument` differ from `\AtEndDocument`? In that it is executed when all files are closed including the `.aux` file. You might be also served with the kernel provided `\AtEndDocument`: make some tests.

Comment: Problably one `out.tmp` should be a `\jobname.tmp`.

Comment: @frougon Yes, I forgot to edit it. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to use this solution to copy resulting PDF from custom output directory (TeX Live compiling option `--output-directory=temp`) to the current directory (in order to let TeXworks display updated output PDF), but it does not work (at least for large PDF, 180MB), in fact the copied PDF is an unusable small PDF, I guess copied before the output PDF is fully written on disk.

Comment: @mmj My advice is to *never ever* use `--output-directory`